# facebook connect with no sdk

Tags: android, facebook, webview, facebook-oauth

I"m trying to implement facebook connect on a WebView. My problem is I couldn't figure out how to implement it.

As per the documentation I called the api as below

```
window.location.href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=148352165368959&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&response_type=code%20token&scope=email,publish_actions"
```

It bring up the confirmation window etc etc but I'm not sure how to navigate back to application and how to get the information from the `https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html`

I've gone through the Bbq plugin but documentation is hard for a newbie like me. Thanks for your time in advance.

can someone atlest point me to a tutorial?

Comment: Check this..http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/

Comment: You can also use Facebook.jar in your project and you can call all the class as you want.

Comment: I'm planning to run it on both web and android webview, so don't wanna restrict it with Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to integrate `Facebook` with your Android application then use the `Facebook` SDK.

**SDK-** https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

**Reference-**  http://developers.facebook.com/android/

Comment: I'm planning to run it on both web and android webview, so don't wanna restrict it with Android SDK.